# onMouseDown/Up на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, html, события

Пишу игру, движение осуществляется с помощью кнопок (стрелок) на которых висит отслеживание onMouseDown (персонаж начинает двигаться) и OnMouseUp (персонаж соответственно останавливается).

На компьютере все замечательно работает, но тачи на мобильных устройствах это события не отслеживают. 
В связи с этим прочел о таком событии как touchstart, решил попробовать использовать его, но на довольной короткой практике я понял что это либо недоработанная функция, либо она предназначена для других целей, бывает touchstart/touchend не срабатывает, бывает наоборот срабатывает даже когда на самом деле событие не произошло. 
Подскажите, может есть более лучший способ?

Comment: Вероятно не срабатывает как нужно из-за [браузерной задержки](https://www.ionic-framework.ru/blog/gibridnye-prilozheniya-i-proklyatie-zaderzhki-v-300-ms/) в 300мс?

Comment: Да в принципе незначительно. Главное нужно чтобы срабатывала функция постоянно и самостоятельно не вызывала другая. А задержка это явление свойственно для мобильных устройств.